# Silent Install of eXist-DB on Windows

Tags: exist-db

I'm trying to silently install eXist-DB on Windows 10, but the process appears to fail when trying to set the password for the database.  Some googling resulted in finding other people with this same issue when attempting to install on a Linux platform, but it was noted the issue was fixed.  However, it seems to still be an issue on the Windows installer, or I'm not doing something properly.  Anyone have any ideas?

**I'm using the following command from an administrative command prompt:**

```
Java.exe -jar "C:\Temp\exist-installer-5.1.1.jar" -options "C:\Temp\install-options"
```

**The install-options file contains the following:**

```
INSTALL_PATH=C:\eXist-db
dataDir=C:\eXist-db\data
adminPasswd=mypassword
```

**Below is the output when I try to run the installation:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Java.exe -jar "C:\Temp\exist-installer-5.1.1.jar" -options "C:\Temp\install-options"
Command line arguments: -options C:\Temp\install-options
Cannot find named resource: 'userInputLang.xml' AND 'userInputLang.xml_eng'
Cannot find named resource: 'userInputLang.xml' AND 'userInputLang.xml_eng'
Cannot find named resource: 'userInputLang.xml' AND 'userInputLang.xml_eng'
Cannot find named resource: 'userInputLang.xml' AND 'userInputLang.xml_eng'

====================

Installation started

Framework: 5.1.3-84aaf (IzPack)

Platform: windows,version=10.0,arch=x64,symbolicName=WINDOWS_10,javaVersion=1.8.0_241
[ Starting to unpack ]
[ Processing package:  (1/13) ]
[ Processing package: Server (2/13) ]
[ Processing package: Apps (3/13) ]
[ Processing package: shared (4/13) ]
[ Processing package: Semver.xq (5/13) ]
[ Processing package: dashboard (6/13) ]
[ Processing package: eXide (7/13) ]
[ Processing package: functx (8/13) ]
[ Processing package: monex (9/13) ]
[ Processing package: packageservice (10/13) ]
[ Processing package: exist-documentation (11/13) ]
[ Processing package: exist-function-documentation (12/13) ]
[ Processing package: markdown (13/13) ]
[ Unpacking finished ]
Installation finished
[ Starting processing ]
Starting process Setting data dir... (1/2)
Starting process Setting admin password... (2/2)
eXist version 5.2.0 (c58d04ec45de50e7738489dee072fcc863dc8b1b), Copyright (C) 2001-2020 The eXist-db Project
eXist-db comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; for details read the license file.

Connecting to database...
Connection to database failed; message: Wrong password for user [admin]
org.xmldb.api.base.XMLDBException: Wrong password for user [admin]
        at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.getUser(DatabaseImpl.java:303)
        at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.getLocalCollection(DatabaseImpl.java:200)
        at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.getCollection(DatabaseImpl.java:178)
        at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.getCollection(DatabaseImpl.java:169)
        at org.xmldb.api.DatabaseManager.getCollection(DatabaseManager.java:235)
        at org.exist.client.InteractiveClient.connect(InteractiveClient.java:301)
        at org.exist.client.InteractiveClient.connectToDatabase(InteractiveClient.java:2123)
        at org.exist.client.InteractiveClient.run(InteractiveClient.java:2227)
        at org.exist.client.InteractiveClient.main(InteractiveClient.java:244)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.exist.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:118)
        at org.exist.start.Main.runEx(Main.java:248)
        at org.exist.start.Main.run(Main.java:123)
        at org.exist.start.Main.main(Main.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.appassembler.booter.AppassemblerBooter.executeMain(AppassemblerBooter.java:257)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.appassembler.booter.AppassemblerBooter.main(AppassemblerBooter.java:77)
Caused by: org.exist.security.AuthenticationException: Wrong password for user [admin]
        at org.exist.security.internal.RealmImpl.authenticate(RealmImpl.java:284)
        at org.exist.security.internal.SecurityManagerImpl.authenticate(SecurityManagerImpl.java:404)
        at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.getUser(DatabaseImpl.java:301)
        ... 22 more
------------------------
Process execution failed

Continue anyway?
------------------------
Enter Y for Yes, N for No:
y
[ Writing the uninstaller data ... ]
[ Console installation done ]

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by putting the install variables directly into the command line rather than an options file.

```
Java.exe -DINSTALL_PATH=C:\eXist-db -DdataDir=C:\eXist-db\data -DadminPasswd=mypassword -jar "C:\Temp\exist-installer-5.2.0.jar" -options-system
```

But the install doesn't create the start menu shortcuts, so I'm doing that with just a basic copy script from a server.

Answer (score 0):

This message seems to imply that there is already an existing database with an admin password set. Did you point the installer at an existing data dir that contains a database?

Comment: No, this is a fresh install.

Comment: Hmm okay, then it sounds like a bug. Could you open an issue - https://github.com/exist-db/exist/issues